# ActiveMQ Broker down. Producer sending messages asynchronously. How to perform re delivery for messages send by Producer? How to use dead letter queue

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, messaging

I have a scenario where my ActiveMQ broker is down. My producer is trying to send messages to this broker in an asynchronous manner ( `connectionfactory.setUseAsyncSend(true)`). Since broker is down no messages reach the broker. I want to perform redelivery for this failed messages, and put them onto a deadletter queue if a fixed number of redelivery attempts are made. If possible send these messages from deadletter queue once the broker is up.
I am using JMSTemplate to send messages and code is in Java.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your broker is down, you won't be able to write to the DLQ, because that's also located on the broker!

The best bet you have is to just handle this failure scenario properly, and do a proper stop until your health check deems the broker is back up. The [docs](http://activemq.apache.org/async-sends.html) aren't so clear about it, but it seems like async sending is ideal when you can tolerate some message loss; it may be async sends don't at first give you an `Exception` if something goes wrong, so you might need to use synchronous if you can't tolerate message loss.

Comment: I tried both.  
jmsConnFactory.setUseAsyncSend(true);
jmsConnFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(true);

When the broker is down, all the threads that made connection to broker is waiting. They are not getting released.